# PermissionAwareActivity not implemented with create-react-native-app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When I try to use `PermissionsAndroid` to require some permissions with my app, I have an error that says:

> Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.

I've created my app with `create-react-native-app`.
After some research, it seems that it should be implement in React-Native already.

I found a post that says I should eject my app from Expo and modify the mainActivity myself and implement it. (Not confirmed)

My question is, why app created by create-react-native-app didn't have PermissionAwareActivity implemented ?
How can I implement it without ejecting from Expo ?

Should I restart my project with react-native init ?

I used the example code from react-native doc for the test:

```
  async requestCameraPermission() {
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
    {
      'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
      'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                 'so you can take awesome pictures.'
    }
  )
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("You can use the camera")
  } else {
    console.log("Camera permission denied")
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}}
```